# UIButton not working in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, ios8

UIButton not work in ios8,the same is working in ios7.When I click on UIButton in iOS8.The following  log comes

> unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent, _windowServerHitTestWindow: ; layer = >

Please advice me to solve this problem.Any advice is appreciable.

Comment: You'll need to show some code or some more detail about how you have created the button and what targets and actions it has.

Comment: Everything is fine.I put unbutton from xib.And also link to the action.It works fine in ios7.

Comment: And one thing is that I change the orientation of UIView from portrait tp landscape at run time